# Git: how to rebase onto previous commit

Tags: git

I'm working on branch C which is based on branch B, then branch A:

`A---B---C`

Is there any commands that can make branch C directly based on branch A like this:

`A---B
  \
   --C`

I have tried `git rebase A` but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git rebase --onto A B C
```

Explanation:

In rebase command, you can define:

1. Branch to rebase (by default = HEAD)
2. The upstream branch of branch-to-rebase
3. Target Branch to rebase to  (by default = upstream branch)

and the command is

```
git rebase --onto TargetBranchToRebaseTo UpstreamBranch BranchToRebase
```

In fact you can almost an exact example in `git help rebase`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```
git checkout C
git checkout -b rebaseTemp
git rebase -i A
```

In the interactive rebase, delete all of the commits that correspond to branch B, but aren't a part of branch C (i.e. the commits that are shared between the two). Complete the rebase, then you will have a new branch (rebaseTemp) that contains what I think you want. You can then merge A into rebaseTemp (which will result in a fast-forward merge).

A branch visualization tool (i.e. `gitk`) is really useful for this scenario, so you can see what commits are shared.

Answer (score 0):

Git has a builtin option to `rebase` that does just that:

```
git checkout C
git rebase --onto A B
```

This rebases all of the commits after B up to C such that they start on A instead of B.